# Stored Procedure (mysql) fails with "can't return a result set in the given context"

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to get this SP to return (leave) if some conditions fails and so forth.

This code validates and it saves the procedure, but when I call the procedure with:

```
CALL ACH_Deposit(30027616,3300012003,200.00,"USD", "127.0.0.1")
```

It fails with error: "Procedure can't return a result set in the given context"

Does anyone have any idea on what the error is?

Procedure code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`redpass_web_urs`@`%` PROCEDURE `ACH_Deposit`(
IN __Account_ID BIGINT,
IN __To_Bank_Account BIGINT,
IN __Amount DECIMAL(10,2),
IN __Currency CHAR(3),
IN __IP_Address VARCHAR(50)
)
COMMENT 'Makes a ACH deposit'
BEGIN

-- Declare Account Parameters
DECLARE _Account_Status INT;
DECLARE __Transaction_ID INT;
DECLARE _Account_Type INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE _Fee INT;

SELECT              
    Account_Status AS _Account_Status,
    Account_Type AS _Account_Type
FROM Account_Users 
WHERE Account_ID = __Account_ID;

main: BEGIN

    -- Step 1, is account active ?
    IF _Account_Status <> 1 THEN
        -- Account must be active (not restricted, closed etc)
        SELECT Response_Code, Description FROM ResponseCodes WHERE Response_Code = 106;
        LEAVE main; -- Here we die..
    END IF;

    -- Step 2, Calculate the FEE (Loading Funds with ACH)
    IF _Account_Type = 1 THEN
        -- Personal Account
        SET _Fee = (SELECT Fee_Template_Personal_1 FROM Fees WHERE Fee_Type_ID = __Fee_Type_ID);

    ELSE
        -- Business Account
        SET _Fee = (SELECT Fee_Template_Business_1 FROM Fees WHERE Fee_Type_ID = __Fee_Type_ID);

    END IF;

    -- Step 3, Check that Fee is not bigger then the actual amount
    IF _Fee > __Amount THEN

        SELECT Response_Code, Description FROM ResponseCodes WHERE Response_Code = 108;
        LEAVE main; -- Here we die..

    END IF;

    -- If we come here, we can make the transactions
    INSERT INTO Bank_Transaction
       (Bank_Account_ID
       ,Transaction_Type
       ,Amount
       ,IP_Address
       ,Pending)
     VALUES
       (__To_Bank_Account
       ,11
       ,__Amount
       ,__IP_Address
       ,1); -- Reserverade pengar

    -- Transaction ID
    SET __Transaction_ID = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());

    -- Deduct the Fee
    INSERT INTO Bank_Transaction
           (Bank_Account_ID
           ,Transaction_Type
           ,Amount
           ,Fee_Type_ID
           ,Fee_Transaction_ID)
        VALUES
           (__To_Bank_Account
           ,4
           ,-__Fee
           ,21
           ,__Transaction_ID);



END main;

SELECT Response_Code, Description, __Transaction_ID AS Transaction_ID
FROM ResponseCodes 
WHERE Response_Code = 1;

END
```

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve multiple resultsets from the stored procs, you should use a client which supports multiple queries.

If you use `PHP`, use `MySQLi` extension and call the procedure using `mysqli_multi_query`.

`MySQL` extension is only able to retrieve the first recordset returned by the proc. To be able to use ti, you should set `CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS` (decimal `131072`) in the parameter `$client_flags` to `mysql_connect`

Comment: Yea I do, but i'm running the query in Sequel PRO, is it Sequel PRO that doesnt support multiple queries?

Comment: @Gomer: never used `Sequel PRO`, but the is possible. If there is a dialog to provide connection options, make sure that something like "use multiple queries" is checked.

Comment: OK, thanks for your replies. When I went through the code now again, I realized that the procedure only should return one resultset in regards to the conditional statements. IF I change the first SELECT to :SET _Account_Status = (SELECT Account_Status FROM Account_Users WHERE Account_ID = __Account_ID);
 SET _Account_Type = (SELECT Account_Type FROM Account_Users WHERE Account_ID = __Account_ID); shouldnt it return only one resultset?

Comment: You actually don't need to use `mysqli_multi_query()` to run a statement that returns multiple result sets. You can use `mysqli_query()` and as long as you are only sending one statement, it will be fine. You can fetch the next resultset just as though you had used `mysqli_multi_query()`.

Comment: But but but :) I only want it to return one resultset :)

Comment: You may need to be aware that when you issue a stored procedure in MySQL, the stored procedure call itself generates an empty resultset (which you may need to dismiss in order to run further statements). This resultset is in addition to results from any SELECT statements you issue in the body of the procedure. This caught me out when I first started using stored procedures, because when I tried to run another query after calling a stored procedure, I would see messages saying "You can't do this now" (because I hadn't yet fetched and discarded the empty stored-procedure-resultset).

Comment: Ok, do you have an example of how I can empty this initial resultset?

Comment: I should be more clear. I don't think that what I described is your problem here. It just occurred to me to warn you that this was something you might have to deal with once you have solved your current problem. (The extra resultset is in any case the last one to be retrieved, not the first.) I do not know what is causing your current problem.

Comment: Thanks both for your replies, I have now found out what the problem was. It was a bug in Sequel PRO that prevented the resultset to be displayed correctly. When I run the query in bash the resultset is return correct. Thanks for your quick answeres, again Stack OVerflow is the best place to get quality support.

Comment: If the solution you arrived at is substantially different to what Quassnoi suggests, consider writing a description of the solution you arrived at, submitting it as an answer, and accepting it.